# Make :after arrow wider

Tags: html, css, styles

I have css:

```
.custom-select::after {
    content: "˅";
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

It creates an arrow:

[arrow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wbyni.png)

i want to make It wider. How can I do this with only css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

simply change ˅ with ﹀.

```
.custom-select::after {
  content: "﹀";
  padding: 12px 8px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 20px;
  top: 8px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-align: center;
  width: 10%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

**Another answer** using css **transform scale** property

```
transform: scale(2,1); 
/* Change the scale as needed*/
```

Where the **first** parameter is the **horizontal** stretch and the **second** parameter is the **vertical** stretch.

Comment: Thanks for reply. Now it's too wide. maybe you can give me a link to source where you dot this arrow or type medium size arrow?

Comment: how about this : ▼

Comment: here is some symbols including arrows https://coolsymbol.com/

Comment: I've updated the answer and included another method.

Comment: `transform: scale(2,1);` Is the right answer. Thank you!